# How to card-reveal button make like FAB button in MaterializeCSS?

Tags: materialize, floating-action-button

I want to make close function of `card-reveal` like FAB button.

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
        <img class="activator" src="http://materializecss.com/images/office.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
        <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">&#xE5D4;</i></span>
        <p><a href="#">This is a link</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-reveal">
        <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i     class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
        <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here is my JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tceydeliler/nkmtLhdL/)
What I need? Although material design Icon now work in this example, I need to make "close" button as fab. It means, even `card-reveal` content scroll down, close button keeps position in `card-reveal` section and visible.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The nature of the card component seems to make this tough to achieve without getting hacky and mixing strange CSS properties. I think the best I can achieve that still looks pleasing is a FAB that travels up and down with the `card-reveal`. Another solution may exist, but it may not be as clean.

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
    <img class="activator" src="http://materializecss.com/images/office.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="card-content">
    <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">
      Card Title
    </span>
    <a class="activator btn-floating red right"></a>
    <p><a href="#">This is a link</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="card-reveal">
    <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">
      Card Title
      <a class="card-title btn-floating red right"></a>
    </span>
    <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Actually not like that. Because ,button not keep position in card. When I scroll down, button goes upside .But I want that, button keep position in card. Like stabdard FAB

Comment: Are you wanting the button to be in the top-right or bottom-right?

Comment: My answer has been edited, though I still don't think it fits your use case exactly.

Comment: I run your codr in jsfiddle and button moves with scroll. My need button still stable while svroll moves up or down. It means button have to be floatted

Comment: My apologies. Please see my edited description as well. I'm sure there is a  way of doing this, but I'm not sure of a clean way. It may take more customization.